# Oracle add group function over result rows

Tags: oracle, aggregate, stdev

I'm trying to add an aggregate function column to an existing result set.  I've tried variations of OVER(), UNION, but cannot find a solution.

Example current result set:

```
ID     ATTR     VALUE
1      score     5
1      score     7
1      score     9
```

Example desired result set:

```
ID     ATTR     VALUE   STDDEV (score)
1      score     5       2
1      score     7       2
1      score     9       2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're after:

- `stddev(value) over (partition by attr)`
- `stddev(value) over (partition by id, attr)`

It just depend on what you need to partition by. Based on sample data the attr should be enough; but I could see possibly the ID and attr.

Example:

```
With CTE (ID, Attr, Value) as (
SELECT 1, 'score', 5 from dual union all
SELECT 1, 'score', 7 from dual union all
SELECT 1, 'score', 9 from dual union all 
SELECT 1, 'Z', 1 from dual union all
SELECT 1, 'Z', 5 from dual union all
SELECT 1, 'Z', 8 from dual)

SELECT A.*, stddev(value) over (partition by attr)  
FROM cte A
ORDER BY attr, value
```

[DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions159.htm) show that by adding an order by to the analytic, one can acquire the cumulative standard deviation per record.

Giving us:

```
+----+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| ID | attr  | value |                  stdev                   |
+----+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Z     |     1 | 3.51188458428424628280046822063322249225 |
|  1 | Z     |     5 | 3.51188458428424628280046822063322249225 |
|  1 | Z     |     8 | 3.51188458428424628280046822063322249225 |
|  1 | score |     5 |                                        2 |
|  1 | score |     7 |                                        2 |
|  1 | score |     9 |                                        2 |
+----+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Depending on the requirement, the OP may even be after `stddev(value) over ()`.

Comment: @xQbert Thank you!